# ASP.NET MVC 2 wildcard route has trouble handling spaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

I've got a wildcard route mapped as below:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{controller}/{action}/{*category}",
            new { controller = "Mall", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This has been working fine until the category has any spaces before or after slashes " / ".

For the category **ART/MUSIC**, it will find the page fine.

For the category **ART / MUSIC**, it will give me a 404 not found.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just answered kind of the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853626/20-followed-by-slash-followed-by-more-data-causes-asp-net-mvc-3-routing-to-fail/4854230#4854230). For completeness:

If an empty space is at the end of any section of the URL before the next slash, it throws a `HttpException` in the `System.Web.Util.FileUtil.CheckSuspiciousPhysicalPath()` method which is handled by MVC and you'll get a HTTP 404 response.

You can verify that yourself by checking the checkbox for `Throw` in:

1. `Visual Studio`
2. `Debug`
3. `Exceptions`
4. `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`

Generally you should not have empty spaces in your URLs. I personally format my urls, that all spaces becomes a dash (-).

Comment: Kind of a bummer as I don't want to go back and redo the whole project as these are user entered items creating the URLs. I guess it makes sense, and I'll keep it in mind in the future. Thanks Martin! ps - sorry for the slow acceptance.