# %20 followed by slash followed by more data causes ASP.NET MVC 3 routing to fail?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

When the characters %20 appears in between paramaters a url, my MVC routing stops considering that a string.

Why is that, and how can I approach handling "%20" characters in my URL?

Example URL

```
http://localhost:40494/ListContents/Delete/asdf%20/5430f394...

public ActionResult Delete(string DNSName, Guid id)
{...}

routes.MapRoute(
    "Delete", // Route name
    "ListContents/Delete/{DNSName}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "ListContents", action = "Delete" } // Parameter defaults
      );
```

**However** 
Both the following URLs work fine

```
http://localhost:40494/ListContents/Delete/asdf%20SOMETHING_HERE/5430f394...

http://localhost:40494/ListContents/Delete/%20asdf/5430f394-946c-4f82-ac13-9d5efafe9127
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an empty space is at the end of any section of the URL before the next slash, it throws a `HttpException` in the `System.Web.Util.FileUtil.CheckSuspiciousPhysicalPath()` method which is handled by MVC and you'll get a HTTP 404 response.

You can verify that yourself by checking the checkbox for `Throw` in:

1. `Visual Studio`
2. `Debug`
3. `Exceptions`
4. `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`

Generally you should not have empty spaces in your URLs. I personally format my urls, that all spaces becomes a dash (-).

Comment: I'll have to debug and see if this is the same thing I see... the space I have is prior to the backslash of the second parameter.

Comment: I changed my answer a little bit, to make clear it happens in any section of the URL with an empty space before the slash.

Comment: Interesting.  Since I'm not dealing with physical paths in MVC,just variables for a database, is this a valid or useful check? Perhaps a XSS check is more effective here.

Comment: I'd guess there are good reasons for this check to be consistent. As I said, spaces are not a good thing in URLs and should be avoided. When you deal with data that becomes part of an URL, format it! Remove whitespace, remove unwanted characters (e.g. :/?!#), remove diacritics (often called accent marks), umlauts and friends.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in the example where it doesn't work is because it can't be parsed as a valid URL, it will be read as

`http://localhost:40494/ListContents/Delete/asdf /5430f394...`

Instead, you would be safe to just remove the `%20` from that url safely.

Comment: That space is there because it is auto-generated by `HTML.ActionLink` on another page.  The space comes from the backing database. What is the best way to make sure this doesn't happen on the rest of my pages?

Comment: @makerofthings7: Do a search on the URL string and make sure it does not have `/` before and after `%20` - this is just my guess. I am not sure of a better way at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the id field of the table isn't a string (nchar(x)). If so, check if the respective id has the exact lenghth defined in the type declaration. If not (if it has less chars), that's the problem (it should have the EXACT lenghth you declared). This worked for me.